# Coordinating threads using shared std::atomic as a counter

Tags: multithreading, atomic

Suppose I have a method called printInOrder:

void printInOrder(const int id, const std::string data) {
}

where id is the thread id (i.e  0, 1 ,2 ..) and data is the data associated with that thread id.

How would I print the data in order such as:

id:0 data corresponding to 0 thread.

id:1 data corresponding to 1 thread. 
..........

Comment: What language is this? And what about this are you stuck doing? You're not just asking us to code it for you are you?

Comment: This is c++. I don't understand how we would use a std::atomic counter to print the data in order. I haven't used std::atomic before.

Comment: What do you think you'd have to do? Ignore c++, just think about the algorithm.

Comment: I think I would have to find a way to keep storing ids and their data. And when I have all the data, I would print it out in ascending order of ids.

Comment: Even while asking a purely algorithmic question, when you are using concepts or use syntax of a particular PL, please tag with that PL. Here [tag:c++]